# Comparing two voices on iphone app?

Tags: iphone

I read many articles dealing with this issue, but I didn't found a solution.

I want to let the user recording his voice, for speaking some words for example, then comparing his pronunciation with a the same words from an existing recorded file.

Any idea?

Comment: Which bit is giving you problems?

Comment: the problem is how to compare audio files, how can i decide if the speech that the user has recorded is the same as a predefined pattern.

Comment: How have you decided what would constitute a match? If they differed slightly, would that still count?

Comment: this is the point, I'll assume they are similar if they match almost 80% for example, it means having moreless same amplitude and fréquence. Like if I say the letter "A", I want to differ it from the letter "I" for example.